# How do I loop the code to play again the guess number?

Tags: oop

The code is fine but I trying to make the code to ask the player to play again which is if the player want to play again then the code continue run. But, it not happened.

```
package exercise;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

public class guessing_game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(101);
    boolean userCorrect = false;
    String userInputString;
    int userGuessedNumber;
    int count = 0;
    String play= "n", UserCorrect="y" ;

    do {
        count=count+1;
        userInputString =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess the number:");
        userGuessedNumber =Integer.parseInt( userInputString );

        if( userGuessedNumber > randomNumber) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,  "Too high, try again");
        }

        else if( userGuessedNumber < randomNumber) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,  "Too low, try again");
        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,  "Yes, you guessed the number, the guessed number is: " + randomNumber);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,  "The number your guessed is " + count);
            userCorrect =true;
            play = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Play again? (y/n) : ");
        }
    }

    while( userCorrect!=true || play == UserCorrect);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare two strings with `==`. This will always return `false` under most conditions.

If you want to compare two strings, use the `.equals(String)` function.

For you, change `play == UserCorrect` to `play.equals(UserCorrect)`.

Comment: How to reset the random number when the player play the game again?

Comment: You can do that in the win scenario.